# What happens to a Settable Future object once the setException method is called on it?

Tags: java, guava, future

I have a Settable Future object "temp" which has a context set to it. Also `temp.addListener(new Runnable{...})` method is called, basically registering a listener to it. However eventually if any exception comes up then `temp.setException()` is called. If the `setException` is called will the listener be de-registered or will the context be cleared (basically will the Settable Future object be damaged after exception is set)?

The flow of code is something like this :-

1. `temp.setContext({temp.set(//some value is set if everything goes right) || temp.setException(//set exception if something comes up)});`
2. `temp.addListener(new Runnable{ run(){temp.get()}})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `setException()`, the `ListenableFuture` [will run its listener](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html#addListener-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-). If you want to write code that will *not* be run in that case, you can use [`Futures.addCallback`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture-com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) instead of `addListener`. (`addCallback` lets you specify code to be run only in case of success or only in case of failure.)

As for what happens with the context: The context isn't part of the `ListenableFuture` API. I don't know if it was added by you or another library. You'd have to consult that class to find out how it behaves.